# how to (run/start) shoutcast via php in linux?

Tags: php, linux, shell, cakephp-2.0, shoutcast

my code now is

```
<?php

$command = "/path/to/sc_serv /path/to/sc_serv.conf";
$PID = shell_exec("$command > /dev/null & echo $!");

?>
```

this will give me the PID number but will close shoutcast 
by ps aux in the console the PID is not found 
and there's no thing in the logs

---

Now I found The problem that the framework will not let this command to be excuted normally !! but I can't know why this is happned !!
my framework is CakePHP

Comment: Why is your `$Command` capitalized the second time around?

Comment: Thank you Philip, I edited it to $command , but this is not the problem , the shoutcast will run but for some thing it will be down again , don't know why this happened

Comment: Seems likely to be a permissions issue. Almost always is when `shell_exec` is involved.  You can test it by logging into the shell and doing an `su apache` -- try to run it as apache. See what happens then, I bet you get some sort of error on startup.

Comment: I tried it but it seems the permession is not the problem here , when I run `/path/to/sc_serv /path/to/sc_serv.conf` in the terminal console by the same user which have the account the shoutcast run , >> and from PHP Script `exec('whoami');` return the same user whom own the server 
and the above code in the question run the shoutcast server but it shutdown again